# Is there any way to perform FOR LOOP in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto

**Edit to clarify my question**

Database: Presto, I'm querying using my company own tool but it's basically similar to MySQL or other stuff.

The purpose is: I have training classes, and I want to evaluate them by comparing a few metrics after and before the training day (says, W+1, W+2, etc. vs pre-training). After doing a few sub-queries, I was able to achieve the table with values as below (each class has its own metric, and is unique).

class | metric | shopid | pre-training | w+1 | w+2 | w+3

A | increasing sth | 1122 | x | x1 | x2 | x3

B | decrease sth | 3322 | y | y1 | y2 | y3 etc.

So now I want to compare the value of W+1, W+2 to pre-training to give a conclusions, for example: if x1 > x -> good, if x2 < x -> bad, etc.

So I write an CASE WHEN statement

```
CASE metric = 'increase sth'
     WHEN x1 > x THEN 'good'
     WHEN x1 < x THEN 'bad' 
CASE metric = 'decrease sth' 
....
```

To apply on columns w+1, w+2, etc. so to get the desired result, but since I have to write the CASE statement for 4 columns, it would be very lengthy and inefficient and repetitive, so I was thinking of LOOP so that I'd just need to write the CASE statement once and it could be apply on all 4 columns without repetition.

I could've extracted the data and done this execution in Python, but I want to learn how to do it in SQL so that I don't have to do extra work after finishing querying.

Sorry, I'm very new to SQL (only about two months in, still working hard enrich my knowledge)

Hope you can help. Much thanks for your help.

Comment: Where are you issuing your query from (eg Python, Java, command line)? Can you provide a more complete example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, I've just edit my post to make my question clearer,  would very appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague, but you can use a `lateral join` to split the rows apart and do the calculation only once.  This will tend to put the values in separate rows:

```
select t.*, diff.*
from t cross join lateral
     (select which, (v.metric - t.metric1) as diff
      from (values (2, t.metric2), (3, t.metric3)
           ) v(which, metric)
     ) diff;
```

You can also put the values back in one row.

That said, you don't seem to have a good foundation in working with relational databases.  The problem starts with your initial structure, where you are storing values *across columns* rather than *in separate rows*.

SQL doesn't have "looping" because it is set-based.  And it is set-based so the optimizer can figure out the best way to run queries.

Comment: Hi, thank for your comment. I'm very new to relational database, only working with it for about 2 months now, so sorry for my naivety. But I think I need to put the values in the separate columns so that it could satisfy my need. I've just edited my post to make it clearer, could you read it and give me any advice thanks. I also read about the lateral join in your example, thanks for that :)